# Openbox root autostart?

Tags: openbox, powertop

I want to run a script as root when the computer starts. This was earlier done in rc.local, but not anymore.

What I've tried:

- putting the script in `/etc/profile.d`
- adding the `/pathto/script.sh` in `/etc/profile`
- added `/pathto/script.sh &` in `/etc/xdg/openbox/autostart`

The script is for setting things powertop recommends; the script works just fine when I run `sudo /pathto/script.sh`.

Comment: FYI, anything in `/etc/profile*` is run when a user (and any and every user) logs in, not when the system boots.

Comment: Ok sure, I then assume that they are run as the user who log in. Sooo where is the file that root runs?

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` would be the right place. Why not keep it there? Why involve Openbox, which is not started when the computer starts but only if someone logs in and chooses that as their window manager?

Comment: Why not? Because it is not used anymore in arch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put it in your crontab with

```
@reboot /pathto/script.sh
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a viable way to do it. Why didn't i think about cron?